# Is there any prerequisite for meeting Thanatos?

Tags: hades

On my 24-th run I've managed to slay the final boss for the first time, yet I've never met Thanatos. He is the only entry I'm missing in the codex. Is there some kind of prerequisite for him to spawn (like feeding enough nectar to Hypnos or something) or am I simply really unlucky?

I have a Steam version of the game bought during this Winter Sale, if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We now have [an official answer from the developer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1145360/discussions/0/2632850242352005470/#c2632850242352634970) to this question, so I'm putting it here:

> It should not be necessary to successfully clear the game to get Thanatos to appear. You just have to run into him in Elysium.The requirements are:
>
> - Have met Alecto or Tisiphone (who can appear after defeating Meg several times)
> - Encounter Thanatos in Elysium (about a 1 in 10 chance per chamber)

> Subsequently he will able to appear in Asphodel or Tartarus as well. (Note I'm spelling out the requirements this directly only because of the problems being reported here.)
> The 1 in 10 chance is purely random so it's possible to get unlucky over long periods of time with regard to his initial appearance.

Answer (score 5):

You've been very very unlucky. According to the wiki page:

> Thanatos occasionally appears at the beginning of regular encounters and challenges Zagreus to see which of them can slay more shades.

There's no pre-requisites for him to spawn, but once you've encountered him in one of these runs you can find him in the House of Hades:

> Thanatos can be found in the same hallway where Achilles keeps guard.

The wiki page doesn't cite any chances, but I suspect you've just been one of the super unlucky players that has never found him.

[Source](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Thanatos)

Answer (score -2):

From what i have heard he only starts showing up after your 33rd run, but after that he can show up anywhere but styxx... Additionally some people said he showed up 1/3 runs after that point... For what that is worth

Comment: I met him on my 26th run. I think you have to defeat the final boss at least once for him to spawn, but don't quote me on that.